# ssh-agent for nested tmux session

Tags: tmux, ssh-agent

```
sessionA
    sessionB
```

I start `tmux` in first `window` of `sessionA` but using this command to wake it: `ssh-agent tmux` that I expect new nested `sessionB` will have its own `ssh-agent` listen for it. And output of `ps aux | grep agent` will show something like:

```
...    0:00 ssh-agent tmux
```

But instead I pass some options to `tmux` like: `ssh-agent tmux <...>` and expect ssh-agent still stay in-process for my new nested session, turn out it does but quickly ended/exited and the output of `ps aux | grep agent` doesn't show `ssh-agent tmux <...>` there.

So why `ssh-agent tmux <...>` get ended?

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer:

If I put `tmux <...>` in subcommand I can keep `ssh-agent tmux` appears in output of `ps aux | grep agent` but now `ssh-agent tmux` is running in `subshell` that wouldn't terminate after server is killed.

EDIT for complete answer: I passed `-d` to detach when pass options to `tmux` so that killed `ssh-agent` process.